# CORS thetransactioncompany does not work for one specific path

Tags: java, cors, put

Currently i'm facing the problem that my `thetransactioncompany corsfilter` on an `Tomcat 7` with `Jersey 1.18` (can't update) works for the path `/v2/users` on `PUT` but not on `/v2/plans`. There is no difference between those - same package only the class is different. I also need to say that `GET`, `POST` works fine only `PUT` doesn't work.

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<!-- CORS FILTER FOR ALLOWING CROSS DOMAIN ACCESS -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

this should allow PUT on all paths after root - or am i wrong?

- also the `OPTIONS` on `/v2/plans` would give me the allowed methods: `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was another `Exception` which was the root cause of the whole thing. Turned on a `deeper Logging` and found it was a `Nullpointer`.

So the `solution` is: `look at the root cause` - and `turn on` a `better logging` with more details in the specific problem.